# Tabularx functionality with small dimensions and embedded logos

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have been trying to learn how to use tabularx for the purpose of creating a simple abstract text table as well as a title table in which I can embed a picture (Logo). I have attached a picture on what these two tables should look like! In addition I will provide the input and output of what I used to create the simple abstract table (Even though it gave me buggy results, probably due to my inexperience with the tabularx command). Any help would be appreciated!

Input:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{|X|}
\hline
Abstract \\ \hline
         \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Output:
—X—Abstract

[image]

Comment: `tabularx`'s first argument is the width of the table, the second argument is the column specifiers. In your example code, the first argument is missing (presumably you wanted something like `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently is, your question is unfortunately somewhat unclear. What exactly is your problem? Is it how you can insert the image into a cell, is it the alignment, the column widths...

However, here is a MWE that creates two tables somewhat similar to the ones in your question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{RGB}{130,130,130}


\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text, provedes the \lipsum command. Do not use in your real document.

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r|X|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}} & \Large \makecell{Some large Text} & \makecell{\scriptsize some text\\ \Large text}\\
\hline
\cellcolor{mylightgray} text text: & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\color{red} some red text} \\
\hline
\cellcolor{mylightgray} some other text: & \begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}lr@{}} text & \multicolumn{1}{|r@{}}{\cellcolor{mylightgray}text:} \end{tabular*}  & \color{red} red text\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{mylightgray}\makecell{Abstract:} \\ \hline
      \lipsum[4] Some more text \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```